# PowerShell Pro Tools multiple forms not running as expected

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I am using PowerShell Pro Tools to create a GUI application that consists of all the common scripts I would run on a clients server:

**main.ps1**
[image]

main.ps1 loads a ServerConnection form on load:

[image]

The code behind this is pretty basic, it just gets the database name and server address for an SQL server:

```
$btnConfirm_Click = {
    $ServerConnectForm.Close();
}

$btnTest_Click = {
    ## Set database connection variables [global]
    $Global:databaseName  = $cmbDatabaseName.Text;
    $Global:serverAddress = $txtServerAddress.Text;

    ## Check db connection
    $testResult = Invoke-SqlCmd -serverInstance $serverAddress -Database $databaseName -Query "SELECT TOP 1 SettingName FROM Settings";

    ## Write results to user
    if ( $testResult -ne $null ) {
        $lblTestResult.ForeColor = "#2acc18";
        $lblTestResult.Text = "Test connection successfull";

        <# If test connection success enable confirm button #>
        $btnConfirm.Enabled = $true;
    }
    else {
        $lblTestResult.ForeColor = "#d61111";
        $lblTestResult.Text = "Test connection failed";
    }
}

$txtServerAddress_Leave = {
    ## Get TRIS database list
    $databaseList = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $txtServerAddress.Text -Query "
        SELECT name FROM   sys.databases WHERE  CASE WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE'  THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.[dbo].[settings]', 'U') END IS NOT NULL 
    "

    ## Clear combo box
    $cmbDatabaseName.Items.Clear();

    ## Add to combo box
    foreach ($database in $databaseList) {
        $cmbDatabaseName.Items.Add($database.ItemArray[0]);
    }
}

. (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'main.designer.ps1')
$MainForm.ShowDialog()
```

The problem is that when I either compile this into an executable or run main.ps1 directly from the project folder, none of the code outside of main.ps1 works. The form will show up but I cannot find a way to get the code behind the form to work. For example in the ServerConnection form, adding a server address does not populate the database names and the test connection button does nothing.

Running from within Visual Studio works as intended.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT :: Show the server connection form call in main.ps1

**MainForm_Load**

```
$MainForm_Load = {
    ## Launch server connection form
    . (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'ServerConnect.designer.ps1');
    $ServerConnectForm.ShowDialog();

    ## Call prereq analysis
    PrereqAnalysis
}
```

Comment: How are you referring the to the controls (I am asking with object scope perspective). I can't see the reference in the code sample.

Comment: There are two files for each form in the case of main: main.ps1 and main.designer.ps1. Main.designer.ps1 defines the controls and is dot sourced at the bottom of the code.

Comment: Do you run anything used by your designer file before the bottom of your code? Usually it is a good practice to run your imports of modules and . sourcing in the top of your code to make sure everything is loaded and ready unless you have a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an issue with the scoping of your code.
If code outside the current scope of a session depends on said session, it will not work.

You could try setting the scope of variables and functions to global while you troubleshoot to see if it makes a difference, then change it back until you find where the scope goes wrong.

Microsoft have a good [MSDoc page about Powershell scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Dot sourcing the script files at the top of main.ps1 worked.